# SQL Server Management Studio - External Tools - Is it possible to have access current database or connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssms, windows-console

I need to develop a small C# console application which needs to have access to currently opened database connection in SQL Server Management Studio. I am thinking to add this tool in `External Tools` and make it available with a single click in menu or toolbar.

I want this program to process some database operations when I click on it from SSMS and it should not ask for any further connection details, and also I don't want to put connection string in app.config (Like in `Query Window`, when I click `Execute` button the query run against currently selected database, I need similar functionality).

Is it possible, if yes then how to get access to current connection?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSMS also for 2008.

Comment: Looks like an SSMS add-in, https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/15/building-a-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @WiktorZychla, yes similar to this. It seems more work. Let me try this option.